# When I try to run "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt", I receive the following error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'"

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

EDIT: I noticed that this problem only occurs when I'm using Jupyter Notebook. When I tried to use Google Colab, it worked fine. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

I tried uninstalling and installing pillow, image, and even matplotlib, but I keep receiving the same error. Note that when I try to run "import image", "import pil" and "import matplotlib", they all worked fine.

This is the exact message:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

in

```
  5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in

```
 34 from cycler import cycler
 35 import matplotlib
 36 import matplotlib.colorbar
 37 import matplotlib.image
 38 from matplotlib import rcsetup, style
```

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in

```
 42 import matplotlib.collections as collections
 43 import matplotlib.colors as colors
 44 import matplotlib.contour as contour
 45 import matplotlib.cm as cm
 46 import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
```

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in

```
 15 import matplotlib.collections as mcoll
 16 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
 17 import matplotlib.text as text
 18 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
 19 import matplotlib.mathtext as mathtext
```

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py in

```
 14 from .font_manager import FontProperties
 15 from .patches import FancyArrowPatch, FancyBboxPatch, Rectangle
 16 from .textpath import TextPath  # Unused, but imported by others.
 17 from .transforms import (
 18     Affine2D, Bbox, BboxBase, BboxTransformTo, IdentityTransform, Transform)
```

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py in

```
  9 from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties, get_font
 10 from matplotlib.ft2font import LOAD_NO_HINTING, LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT
 11 from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
 12 from matplotlib.path import Path
 13 from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
```

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py in

```
 25 
 26 import numpy as np
 27 from PIL import Image
 28 from pyparsing import (
 29     Combine, Empty, FollowedBy, Forward, Group, Literal, oneOf, OneOrMore,
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Answer (score 2):

I found that this issue only occurred when using Jupyter Notebook, so after several tries I uninstalled Anaconda and reinstalled it and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing like this

import PIL as Image

Comment: When I tried it, I received the following: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'"

Comment: Try "pip install pillow" or use  "conda install pillow" for anaconda distribution.   if this does not work then try doing a Virtual Environment and then perform these steps.

Answer (score 0):

It's `import PIL` not `import pil`. Normally you should also be able to see which line causes the error. There is nothing wrong with the matplotlib import that you mentioned.

Comment: When I tried to do that, I received the following error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'". And sorry I should've been more specific, this line is what's causing the error: "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"

Answer (score 0):

1. First, install PIL through command line `python -m pip install pillow`.
2. Second, use it, do in your script `from PIL import Image`.

Comment: I tried that, but using "PIL" doesn't work. "from pil import Image" is what worked. I also noticed that this issue occurs only when I'm using Jupyter Notebook. When I used Google Colab, the code worked fine.

Comment: @NadineAmin I think `pil` (lowercase) is some wrong module, maybe it is very old module version, or some alternative clone. Also probably you installed using `pip install pil`. But official most-recent module should be installed as `pip install pillow` (notice pillow not pil). Also this pillow module is used through `import PIL` (uppercase). I don't suggest using other modules besides this one mentioned by me, even if code syntactically works correctly.